Difference between npm package @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity and @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider
What's the main difference between @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity and @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider?
Both seem to have essential support for cognito usage.
Thanks
